# my wordpress own theme developed is displaying symbols on the post how to fiix it

Tags: wordpress

[image: Image showcasing the error]

How can I fix this bug?

On the post-it shows the unknown symbol but when I click on it to read the content it is displayed well.

Note: My website content is in Portuguese, that is... in my official language.

Comment: You will need to share the code that is rendering this part of the page so that someone can identify what is causing that.

Comment: take a look of a picture of my screen. i'd like to paste the code here but i'm no yet familiar with the site as a user i'm having problems

Answer (score 0):

you have some unformatted unicode symbols in your content.

For fixing this, go to that page or template and delete that extra symbol and insert that symbol again manually.

for example, if it is a single quote ', then delete that single quote manually and insert it one more time.

Comment: are you saying that i have to cut the content and paste?